# Sorting a vector of custom objects with const member

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I would like to sort a vector holding objects of a class with a `const` member variable.
Unfortunately, I get an error stating that there is *"no matching function for call to "swap""*.

When I remove the `const` keyword for **`id`**, then `std::sort()` works with both the overloaded `operator<()` and the custom compare function.

Why is this the case? Can I in general not sort objects belonging to a class with a const member variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    const int id;
    A(int id) : id(id) {}
    bool operator<(const A &other) const
    {
        return id < other.id;
    }
};

bool cmp(const A &lhs, const A &rhs)
{
    return lhs.id < rhs.id;
}

int main()
{
    vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(3);
    vec.emplace_back(0);
    vec.emplace_back(2);
    vec.emplace_back(1);
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
}
```

Comment: @EvanTeran `A` has copy and move constructors. It's the assignment operators that are the problem for `std::swap`.

Comment: @aschepler thanks for the correction. I made sure to get it right when converting my comment to an answer :-)

Comment: `A(int id) : id(id) {}` this is not a good idea

Comment: @Slava Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the way that sort is going to be implemented is that it will swap objects as needed. A class with a const member and no copy or move assignment operators is not going to be "swappable".

I would probably make the `id` member private and non-const. Then I'd have it accessed via a getter (but not providing a setter). Making it logically const, but the class would be copyable.

Something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int id) : id_(id) {}

    bool operator<(const A &other) const {
        return id_ < other.id_;
    }

    int id() const { return id_; }

private:
    int id_;
};
```