# Is it impossible to sort custom class with const member by move symantic?

Tags: c++, sorting, constants, move

I saw this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47317853/8106257

But, I don't satisfying logical const.

Is there any other way to sort custom class object with const member variable?

I was firstly thought that how about using move constructor but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class City
{
private:
    const int _cost;
    const int _customer;

public:
    City(int cost, int customer) : _cost(cost), _customer(customer)
    {

    }
    City(const City&& city) : _cost(city._cost), _customer(city._customer)
    {

    }
    City& operator=(const City& city) = delete;
    bool operator<(const City& city) const
    {
        return false;
    }
};
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator()(const City& l, const City& r) { return l < r; }
};

int main()
{
    int C, N;
    std::cin >> C >> N;

    std::vector<City> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int cost, customer;
        std::cin >> cost >> customer;
        vec.emplace_back(cost, customer);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Comparator());
}
```

Comment: `but it didn't work.` - Why not? What error did you get? Edit the question and add this information please.

Comment: Looks like you need an explicit move assignment operator.

Comment: But the move assignment operator will not be able to set trhat sort. Why can't you have the copy assignment operator with this struct?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox ok. I'm trying to add copy constructor like City(const City& city) : _cost(city._cost), _customer(city._customer) { }
and using delete keyword to move constructor and assignment operator then sort require move constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: In the given case there is no possibility of move, because there is nothing which can be moved as it is always a copy.

Comment: Well, you can sort a vector of *indices*, and then create a new vector of `City` (once you add some accessors to this class), but why aren't you satisfied of the linked answer?

Comment: In C++, an object *is* the bytes of it's storage. `std::sort` doesn't invalidate references, so you can hold on to a reference to an element, and see that it changes value after the sort.

Comment: "But, I don't satisfying logical const." Yes you do. All your data members are `const`

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort your `std::vector` because the `std::sort` uses move assignment and move construction to sort the elements. If you take a look here: [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)
you will find:

> Type requirements:
>
> > The type of dereferenced RandomIt must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable and MoveConstructible.

You can't assign nor move assign as your members are const.

This makes it impossible to use `std::sort` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible prior to c++20 but now is. Note there is no need for move semantics since the types are all POD types where move semantics don't do anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class City
{
private:
    const int _cost;
    const int _customer;

public:
    City(int cost, int customer) : _cost(cost), _customer(customer){}
    City& operator=(const City& city)
    {
        if (this!= &city)
            std::construct_at(this, city);  // no destruction needed since trivially destructable
        return *this;
    }
    // change as required to the sorting reqs
    bool operator<(const City& city) const
    {
        return _customer < city._customer;
    }
};
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator()(const City& l, const City& r) { return l < r; }
};

int main()
{
    int C, N;
    std::cin >> C >> N;

    std::vector<City> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int cost, customer;
        std::cin >> cost >> customer;
        vec.emplace_back(cost, customer);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Comparator());
}
```

compiler explorer
https://godbolt.org/z/hE43z7763